# Is it possible for the dimension of AS to be greater than the dimension of S

Tags: linear-algebra

When  subspace S of kDdimension is hit with a matrix A that hits on kDimension  and hangs in nDimension, a subspace AS of nDimension is created. But Is it possible for the dimension of AS to be greater than the dimension of S. And is there a reason as to why it may or may not be possible for the dimension to be greater?

Answer (score 1):

Let $s_1,\dots,s_k$ be a basis for $S$. Then, since any element of $AS$ is on the form $As$ for some $s\in S$, and since such $s$ can be written as a linear combination $s=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i s_i$, we get that
$$As = A\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i s_i = \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i (As_i)$$
and therefore $AS = \operatorname{span}( As_1,\dots,As_k)$ and we get that the dimension of $AS$ is at most $k$.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you should have the knowledge to find out on your own. In case you tried or don't want to try it on your own, here is an answer.

**Solution**

The dimension can't be bigger. Here is a proof why:

Suppose you have some elements $\{ b_i\}_{i=1}^j \subset AS$, which are linearly independend. Then, $b_i=Aa_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$ and for some $a_i\in S$. Then, the $a_i$'s are linearly independend: Suppose that for some $x_i$'s within your given field, $0=\sum_{i=1}^j x_i a_i$. Therefore,
$$0=A\sum_{i=1}^j x_i a_i=\sum_{i=1}^j x_i Aa_i=\sum_{i=1}^j x_i b_i$$
Thus, by the linear indepencene of the $b_i$'s, each $x_i$ must be zero. Therefore, $\{ a_i\}_{i=1}^j\subset S$ is a linear independent set. Especially, the dimension of $AS$ is lower or equal than the one of $S$.